# php download file is not working, downloading a empty file

Tags: php

im listing files from a sub directory and trying to download them. below is my script. download popup comes but it shows 0 size and downloads empty files. but when i set the $directory to root instead of sub directory folder, download works and saves file with content. Please help, how can I download the files with below script by setting the $directory to sub directory.

index.php

```
$directory  = "folder";  //this is my sub directory
$images = scandir($directory);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
$count=1;
echo '<table border=1>';
foreach($images as $dispimage){
    if(!in_array($dispimage, $ignore)){
    echo "<tr id='del$count'>
    <td>$count</td>
    <td>$dispimage</td>     

    <td><a href=\"browserProcess.php?file=$dispimage\">Download</a>

    </tr>";
    $count++;
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

browserProcess.php

```
  if ($_GET['file']){
  $file = $_GET['file'];
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($file);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Don't use this code. You're allowing users to download **ANY** file on your server for which they know the path name. This is HIGHLY dangerous. If you want to leave yourself open for a complete data suck, then use `readfile("folder/$file")` instead.

Comment: @MarcB thanks. the sub directory is not static folder name, and permission levels vary on users. im trying to setting it up dynamically like this readfile("admin/userDirectories/$user_id/$file"); but its not working, if i use sub directory folder name statically instead of $user_id it works, but i want to use the sub directory dynamically. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

@Marc B comments are correct. You are allowing users to download any file on your server.

The reason the file you download is always empty is because browserProcess.php is looking in the wrong directory. In index.php you scan the './folder' directory while browserProcess.php looks for the file in './' instead of './folder'.

If you are using this script to learn about file operations and to learn how to serve files for download then it's ok, so long as you know that this is not code that can ever be put into production or a project as it contains huge security holes.